# How do I create Primary Keys determined on dates in PANDAS?

Tags: python, pandas, primary-key

I'm trying to create a primary key column for a dates table. The first primary key being 1, and then += 1 with each new date.

Here is the code which I'm using:

```
date_list = []
df['date_id'] = 0

for date in df['just_date']:
    if date not in date_list:
        df['date_id'] += 1
        date_list.append(date)
    else:
        df['date_id'] += 0
```

The problem is that the newly created df['date_id'] column is populated with nothing but '19', the number of unique dates in the table.

Comment: You can use `groupby()` and `cumcount` and then merge.

Comment: Have you read the Pandas docs?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're accessing the dataframe  where you want to be accessing the specific row:

```
date_list = []
df['date_id'] = 0

for date in df['just_date']:
    if date not in date_list:
        date['date_id'] += 1
        date_list.append(date)
    else:
        date['date_id'] += 0
```

should work